# How do you update popups in Azure map from a Microsoft Synapse database

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-maps

I am new to Azure Maps. I am using the Azure maps example showPopupOnHover.html. How would I connect to an Azure Synapse database to retrieve values to display when I hover over the markers?  The database contains many rows so I will have to retrieve the most current data per map point.  Do you recommend using node and javascript?  Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you will already have the latitude, longitude and an ID for each data point on the map. If not, you will need a service to retrieve that information from the database. An Azure Function (any programming language), Azure Web app or ASP.NET app is a good option to for a light weight service.

From there, to display details for a location I would use a click event instead of a hover event just because of the frequency at which the hover event would fire (it would potentially hammer your service). When a user clicks on a location I would load a popup with an animated image for loading, and make a request using the ID of the point to the service to retrieve details for that location. When the service responses, update the content of the popup.

Comment: I have the lat & lon for each point, about 15 points.  The lat & lon are also in the database.  I am a newbie to all of this.  So I should create say an Azure Function, then use this function in my javascript code to query the database, then use the retrieved data to create the info for the popup?

Comment: Take a look at this blog for a fairly similar architecture: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/rest-api-with-azure-functions-javascript-and-azuresql/